# How can I make a column that the number is counted automatically?

Tags: booktabs

I have a booktabs (longtable) and I make a column *Order*. I have to input the number 1, 2, 3, ... by hand. How can I make a column that the numbers are counted automatically?
My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,longtable,fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*{5}{>{$}c<{$}}}
\endfirsthead  % blank header on first page
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{(\emph{array continued from previous page})}
\endhead
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{(\emph{array continued on next page})}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\begin{tabular}{@{}cllll@{}}
\toprule[1pt]
Order & point $A$  & point $B$  & point $C$  & point $D$  \\ \midrule
1     & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ \\
2     & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ \\
3     & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ & $(1,2,-6)$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your use of `tabular` inside of `longtable` utterly defeats the purpose of `longtable`, which is to allow pagebreaks inside the tabular material.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58138/15925 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21243/15925

Comment: @Mico Instead input, example `$\left (\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{3}{4}\right )$`, Can I reduce to \left (\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{3}{4}\right ) (obmit $$) but receive the same result?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Please see my answer, in which I make the four data columns be in math mode automatically; this should let you insert expressions such as `\left( \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{3}{4} \right)` in various cells. However, I don't think it's a good idea to use `\dfrac` in tabular material. Why not use inline-fraction notation, i.e., `(1/2,  3/4)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution automates the automatic insertion of row numbers in the first column in the body of the `longtable` environment, in a way that allows cross-referencing rows using the basic `\label`-`\ref` system. The key part of the solution is the creation of a dedicated column type, called `N` in the code below.

The solution also gets rid of the `tabular` environment *inside* the `longtable` environment. Having a `tabular` environment inside a `longtable` utterly defeats the purpose of using a `longtable` environment, which is to allow page breaks, as needed, in the interior of a `longtable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} % change font

\usepackage{amsmath,array,longtable,booktabs}
\newcounter{rownum}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rownum}\therownum}l}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macros
\newcommand\ml[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ N *{4}{C} }
%% headers and footers
\toprule[1pt]
\ml{Order} & \mc{point $A$} & \mc{point $B$} & \mc{point $C$} & \mc{point $D$}  \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead  % blank header on first page

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{(\emph{array continued from previous page})}\\
\addlinespace
\ml{Order} & \mc{point $A$} & \mc{point $B$} & \mc{point $C$} & \mc{point $D$}  \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{(\emph{array continued on next page})}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of longtable
%% Note the generally "empty" first column -- empty except for \label directives
 & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) \\
 & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) \\
 & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) \\
 & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) \\
 \label{row:v} & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) \\
 & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) & (1,2,-6) \\
\end{longtable}

A cross-reference to row \ref{row:v} of the table.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I align the numbers in column Order is center?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Absolutely. Just change `\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rownum}\therownum}l}` to `\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rownum}\therownum}c}`, i.e., change the last `l` to `c`.

Comment: How can I align left every columns?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Have you tried changing the underlying column types from `c` to `l`?

Comment: I am trying to find where is underlying column?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Can you spot the "underlying column type" in `\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}`? Hint: it's not `l` or `r`.