# more contents in a table, help me in creating this table in latex

Tags: tables

[image][image]
How can i create a table like this. I have tried many methods but I'am not able to create a table like this. Please friends help me out.

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|r|r|r|}\hline

Comparative methods & Guolin,Deyun and Jason (2008) & Sushmitha and Malviya (2013) & Raad, Ghazali and Loay (2014) & Mukesh Tiwari and Dr. Rakesh (2017) & Proposed method\\\hline

Types of vehicles studied & Cars & Cars and Trucks & Cars & Cars, Bikes and Trucks & Cars, Bikes and trucks\\ \hline

Segmentation method & Frame subtraction and background update & Background subtraction & Background subtraction & Optical flow & Background subtraction with Discrete cosine transform \\ \hline

Classification method & X & Centroid  method & Contour Tracking method & Silhouette tracking & Multi-SVM classification\\ \hline

Vehicle counting accuracy & 88.6\% & 91\% & 92.04\% & 93\% & 95.18\% \\ \hline


\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: please show a small complete table that shows what you tried, and what error you got, do not expect people to type in that text from an image

Comment: is here any option there to post the screenshot of what the output i got

Comment: i have added the screenshot please look into it and get me a solution.

Comment: Hi. Maybe you misunderstand David and Bernhard. Have a look at the other questions here and then post a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: I need code for atleast 3 columns and 3 rows, i'll cope up with it. please help friends.

Comment: leandriis i'am not able to understand the code in the link which you sent.

Comment: Again, please have a look at: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe. This is (typically) not a "Do-It-For-Me" site :).

Comment: i'am not able to find what I need in this link , can anyone help me up with this.

Comment: @rakeshv you must understand that people here can only help if you provide a starting point. As previously said, this is not a *do it for me* site, so IMHO demands like *get me a solution* are not very nice to the people trying to help.

Comment: do not post an _image_ of your code post the text as text, prefereably a small one page document that just shows the table.

Comment: i have post the code as text as you have said @DavidCarlisle . please help me out.

Comment: as explained above a "MWE" document would have been better than a fragment, but this once, I'll post something....

Answer (score 3):

> Too long for a comment.

There are LaTeX table generators that can help you in the beginning.

- http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables
- or more general [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online)

In addition, there are already many questions regarding your problem* as I understand it:

- [How to break a line in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table)
- [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)
- [Automatic line-break in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/automatic-line-break-in-tabular/166746)
- [Automatic line-breaks in tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137475/automatic-line-breaks-in-tables)
- [Automatic line-breaks in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318872/automatic-line-breaks-in-a-table/324204)

<sup>*Line Breaks in Cells of a LaTeX Table</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\leavevmode\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}p{1.6cm}}@{}}\hline
Comparative methods & Guolin, Deyun and Jason (2008) & Sushmitha and Malviya (2013) & Raad, Ghazali and Loay (2014) & Mukesh Tiwari and Dr. Rakesh (2017) & Proposed method\\\hline
Types of vehicles studied & Cars & Cars and Trucks & Cars & Cars, Bikes and Trucks & Cars, Bikes and trucks\\ \hline
Segmentation method & Frame subtraction and background update & Background subtraction & Background subtraction & Optical flow & Background subtraction with Discrete cosine transform \\ \hline
Classification method & X & Centroid  method & Contour Tracking method & Silhouette tracking & Multi-SVM classification\\ \hline
Vehicle counting accuracy & 88.6\% & 91\% & 92.04\% & 93\% & 95.18\% \\ \hline


\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I have copied the layout shown with all 6 columns using the same centred format but especially the last column would probably look better set `\raggedright`, and possibly wider.

Comment: thankyou sir @DavidCarlisle . now how to put the vertical line ,its a table there are only horizontal lines in the table you have coded sir.

Comment: @rakeshv if you really want them just put the `|` back  `|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\leavevmode\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}p{1.6cm}|}`

Comment: @rakeshv I recommend not to add any vertical lines. They are not only useless but also make the table more complicated.